# Can't store is_confirmation_enabled via API

Tags: civievent, api, apiv4

I can't for the life of me store the value of is_confirmation_enabled for creating a new event via API. This is in a PHP file that creates new events on the front end of Joomla based on input collected in a 3rd party (Joomla-based) form. The event gets created just fine with all the data points as entered by the user, but the is_confirmation_enabled always ends up being "no". Tried API 3 and 4 - same results. If I try via API explorer, it works. Really lost here ... may have to resort to a SQL query to update the event record, instead, which would be a bummer. Here's my code:

```
$results = \Civi\Api4\Event::create(FALSE)
  ->addValue('id', '')
  ->addValue('title', $evtInfo['Title'])
  ->addValue('start_date', $evtInfo['StartDate'])
  ->addValue('end_date', $evtInfo['EndDate'])
  ->addValue('event_type_id', $evtInfo['Type'])
  ->addValue('Additional_Event_Info.Pace', $evtInfo['Pace'])
  ->addValue('Additional_Event_Info.Trail_Page', $evtInfo['TrailPage'])
  ->addValue('is_online_registration', $evtInfo['Registration'])
  ->addValue('Additional_Event_Info.Chapter', $evtInfo['Chapter'])
  ->addValue('description', $evtInfo['Description'])
  ->addValue('is_active', $evtInfo['Status'])
  ->addValue('is_public', TRUE)
  ->addValue('default_role_id', 1)
  ->addValue('is_template', FALSE)
  ->addValue('template_title', '')
  ->addValue('is_share', FALSE)
  ->addValue('is_confirm_enabled', TRUE)
  ->addValue('is_email_confirm', TRUE)
  ->addValue('confirm_email_text', 'Thank you for registering for Evergreen MTB event - please see the details below.\r\n\r\n-Evergreen MTB')
  ->addValue('confirm_from_email', 'events@evergreenmtb.org')
  ->addValue('confirm_from_name', 'Evergreen MTB Events')
  ->execute();
```

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Can you try in the API explorer to see if you get the same results?

Comment: Try removing the line `->addValue('id', '')` that's kinda weird

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it works via API explorer; removing ->addValue('id', '') didn't do anything ... thanks for the suggestions, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As humiliating as it is, I want to post an answer to keep the suggestions in the comments and to perhaps give someone a hint who may make a similar mistake to mine. I had another line of code later in the file changing the is_confirm_enabled value to "0" ... yup, I did say humiliating. Cheers.